# Why does the text in my PDF become invisible when I switch to another text field?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader, adobe-reader-dc

I'm using Adobe Acrobat Reader DC to view a PDF file that somebody else created. There are editable text fields in the document that I can write text in, like this:

[image]

But when I switch to another text field, the text in the first field becomes invisible:

[image]

The text in the first field is still there, so if I switch the focus back to it, it'll still have the text that I typed.

Comment: Is it possible to provide a link to the PDF?

It'll be easier to answer with that, but just in general, I doubt you'll be able to fix the problem without editing the PDF. Possibly the text form field is behind another element, or the font color is white, or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

I might be like 5 years too late, but you can Right click on the text box, click 'Text style', then 'clear formatting' and your text should stay in view.